# vim build from source: E518 error

Tags: vim, configuration, configuration-files

Vim is built from source. I've followed the tutorial [here](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source).

Now my default edit if `Vim version 7.4.397`

Here's just the beginning (start line = 1= of my `.vimrc` file:

```
"------------------------------------
" Vundle configuration
set nocompatible
filetype off
set rpt+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle
call vundle#rc()

" Vundle management (for updates)
Bundle 'gmarik/vundle'
Bundle 'bling/vim-arline'
```

When I try to launch vim I get:

```
Error detected while processing /root/.vimrc:
line    5:
E518: Unknown option: rpt+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle
line    6:
E117: Unknown function: vundle#rc
line    9:
E492: Not an editor command: Bundle 'gmarik/vundle'
line   10:
E492: Not an editor command: Bundle 'bling/vim-arline'
```

How comes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short form of `'runtimepath'` is `rtp`, not `rpt`:

```
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle
```

The following errors are caused by the fact that the *Vundle* plugin cannot be found.

I recommend to always use the long form in configuration, for clarity. Use the short form only interactively to save typing.

Comment: Tens of thousands of "reputation points" and we are here, fixing random strangers' typos…

Comment: Such a shame... **`(>.<)"`** Thank you very much!

Comment: Sometimes you can't see the forest for all the trees; that can happen to anyone :-)